# I'm learning figurative language in reading class

Tags: word-usage

What kind of figurative language is an author using when he says the boats, " hiccuped, growled, and whined"?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. It's figurative language. Were you told there are various types of figurative language?

Comment: @ralph.m The question is perfectly clear and appropriate; any literature student would be able to tell you that there are **many** types of [figures of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech).

Answer (score 2):

At the most basic level, this is a [**metaphor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor):

> A metaphor is a figure of speech that, for rhetorical effect, directly
>   refers to one thing by mentioning another.
>
> [Wikipedia, citing Merriam-Webster]

In this case, the boat is described as doing things that an inanimate object cannot do: actions that would normally be attributed to humans or other animals. The metaphor gives "life" to the boat, making the description of the boat's sounds more vivid.

Furthermore, this particular kind of metaphor is an example of [**pathetic fallacy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathetic_fallacy):

> The phrase pathetic fallacy is a literary term for the attributing of
>   human emotion and conduct to things found in nature that are not
>   human. It is a kind of personification that occurs in poetic
>   descriptions, when, for example, clouds seem sullen, when leaves
>   dance, or when rocks seem indifferent. The British cultural critic
>   John Ruskin coined the term in his book, Modern Painters (1843–60).
>
> [Wikipedia, citing *The Penguin Dictionary of Philosophy*, *Glossary
>   of Literary Terms* and *The New Encyclopædia Britannica*].

Lastly, it's an example of [**zoomorphism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoomorphism):

> Attributing animal form or other animal characteristics to anything
>   other than an animal; similar to but broader than anthropomorphism.
>
> [Wikipedia]

This seems a more exact definition than that provided by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zoomorphism):

> 2: the use of animal forms in art or symbolism

While many animals are capable of hiccuping, growling and whining - dogs, for instance - the zoomorphism could be interpreted as specifically referring to humans, in which case it would be [**anthropomorphism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism):

> Anthropomorphism is the attribution of human traits, emotions, or
>   intentions to non-human entities.
>
> [Wikipedia, citing *Oxford English Dictionary*]

Answer (score 1):

I would consider this phrase to be both a personification. It would be a personification since it gives a non-living item(boats) a quality humans would have(they are hiccuping and whining). Merriam Webster describes personification as "attribution of personal qualities"(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/personification). Good question!

Comment: Good answer, but what would be most helpfull and fit in with the site rules, you could add a referenced definition of personification. Please take the tour and read the guidance in the help center for tips.